# Need to press power button three times to turn screen on using Screen Off and Lock

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, screen

I'm using the **Screen Off and Lock 1.7.1** application on **Android 4.1.1**. The phone model is **Huawei G510-0010**.

After I turned off the screen using that application, I have to press the power button three times to turn the screen on. Using the power button to screen off/on, it is ok.

I uninstalled 1.7.1 and installed 1.10 which already works perfectly in other devices, but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my mind to use [Gravity Screen - On/Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plexnor.gravityscreenofffree&hl=en).

> This app turns automatically your screen off when you put your phone
>   into your pocket or onto a table and turn the screen on when you take
>   it out or up. No need to touch any button and you are ready to go.